# Ubuntu no internet and wifi after system update - network unclaimed

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, 20.04, ethernet

i read a lot about this topic, but i cant find any solution. So my problem is after an update i do not have any ethernet or wireless connection. Seems to be i do not have as well r8168 or r8169 installed driver. Here is some information:

**lspci -v**

```
21:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8192EE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
    DeviceName: Broadcom 5762
    Subsystem: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8192EE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
    Flags: fast devsel, IRQ 11
    I/O ports at e000 [disabled] [size=256]
    Memory at f7600000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [disabled] [size=16K]
    Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [50] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [70] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [140] Device Serial Number 01-91-81-fe-ff-4c-e0-00
    Capabilities: [150] Latency Tolerance Reporting
    Capabilities: [158] L1 PM Substates

22:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 10
    I/O ports at d000 [size=256]
    Memory at f7504000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Memory at f7500000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [50] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [70] Express Endpoint, MSI 01
    Capabilities: [b0] MSI-X: Enable- Count=4 Masked-
    Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [140] Virtual Channel
    Capabilities: [160] Device Serial Number 01-00-00-00-68-4c-e0-00
    Capabilities: [170] Latency Tolerance Reporting
    Capabilities: [178] L1 PM Substates
```

**lshw -c netowork**

```
WARNING: you should run this program as super-user.
  *-network UNCLAIMED       
       description: Network controller
       product: RTL8192EE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:21:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: ioport:e000(size=256) memory:f7600000-f7603fff
  *-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Ethernet controller
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:22:00.0
       version: 15
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: ioport:d000(size=256) memory:f7504000-f7504fff memory:f7500000-f7503fff
WARNING: output may be incomplete or inaccurate, you should run this program as super-user.
```

**lsmod**

```
xt_conntrack           16384  1
xt_MASQUERADE          20480  1
nf_conntrack_netlink    49152  0
nfnetlink              16384  2 nf_conntrack_netlink
xfrm_user              36864  1
xfrm_algo              16384  1 xfrm_user
xt_addrtype            16384  2
iptable_filter         16384  1
iptable_nat            16384  1
nf_nat                 45056  2 iptable_nat,xt_MASQUERADE
nf_conntrack          147456  4 xt_conntrack,nf_nat,nf_conntrack_netlink,xt_MASQUERADE
nf_defrag_ipv6         24576  1 nf_conntrack
nf_defrag_ipv4         16384  1 nf_conntrack
bpfilter              884736  0
br_netfilter           28672  0
bridge                192512  1 br_netfilter
stp                    16384  1 bridge
llc                    16384  2 bridge,stp
aufs                  258048  0
overlay               118784  0
nls_iso8859_1          16384  2
nvidia_uvm           1019904  0
nvidia_drm             49152  0
nvidia_modeset       1183744  1 nvidia_drm
nvidia              19746816  2 nvidia_uvm,nvidia_modeset
joydev                 24576  0
input_leds             16384  0
kvm_amd                98304  0
kvm                   712704  1 kvm_amd
drm_kms_helper        217088  1 nvidia_drm
cec                    53248  1 drm_kms_helper
crct10dif_pclmul       16384  1
crc32_pclmul           16384  0
ghash_clmulni_intel    16384  0
rc_core                57344  1 cec
aesni_intel           372736  0
drm                   552960  3 drm_kms_helper,nvidia_drm
crypto_simd            16384  1 aesni_intel
cryptd                 24576  2 crypto_simd,ghash_clmulni_intel
fb_sys_fops            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
syscopyarea            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
sysfillrect            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
glue_helper            16384  1 aesni_intel
sysimgblt              16384  1 drm_kms_helper
efi_pstore             16384  0
ccp                    98304  1 kvm_amd
sch_fq_codel           20480  1
parport_pc             45056  0
ppdev                  24576  0
lp                     20480  0
parport                65536  3 parport_pc,lp,ppdev
ip_tables              32768  2 iptable_filter,iptable_nat
x_tables               45056  5 xt_conntrack,iptable_filter,xt_addrtype,ip_tables,xt_MASQUERADE
autofs4                45056  2
btrfs                1290240  1
blake2b_generic        20480  0
xor                    24576  1 btrfs
raid6_pq              114688  1 btrfs
libcrc32c              16384  3 nf_conntrack,nf_nat,btrfs
hid_generic            16384  0
usbhid                 57344  0
hid                   135168  2 usbhid,hid_generic
uas                    28672  0
usb_storage            73728  2 uas
xhci_pci               20480  0
ahci                   40960  2
xhci_pci_renesas       20480  1 xhci_pci
libahci                36864  1 ahci
```

My kernel version is:
**linux-image-5.8.0.45-generic**

i have tried to boot also inside my older kernel version (**linux-image-5.8.0.41-generic**
) , but again i have no internet connection as well i do not know how should i proceed

I have tried also by downloading the r8168 or r8169 driver on usb stick and try to run int but then i recieve:

```
/lib/modules/kernel-version/build no such directory or file.
```

I saw that you should install as well linux-headers for the kernel to have this folder, but i dont have any ehternet or wifi and cant do it ...

Comment: Please clarify how you updated your kernel.

Comment: sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
And also from software and updates there was a notification which i accepted to update all the software.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you used r8168 before and r8169 is blacklisted. Just remove the r8169 blacklisting.

Comment: Hi, but r8169 or r8168 cannot be found of all blacklist in etc/modprobe.d ?